# pass arguments inside splitted methods

Tags: python, class

I need to split class methods in several files. Functionality need to by that I can pass inside method all variables defined in self and receive new self variables defined inside the method.

My attempt:

Below code works, but I don't know if this is the best/proper solution.

Base:

```
from calculate_function import function


class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = -2
        self.x = 1
        self.z, self.result = function(self)
```

calculate_function.py:

```
def function(self):
    z = 2
    result = z + self.x
    return z, result
```

For above I pass self inside new function for collect all init variables, then define new self variable/results.

There will by much more functions inside different files that will done some calculations and create new variables for instance of class.

**Question**

What I need is to pass each created self variable to each function.
For above code the solution is proper defined or there is better option to this?

Comment: If you think of `function` as something *mutating an object*, why `return` anything from it at all? It could simply take in the object and mutate it into the desired state. Arguably it should probably be a method on the class then, but it doesn't have to be. I'd argue that mutating the object *and* returning values which then just get assigned to the object anyway is somewhat weird, it should only do one of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to externalize some part of your class code to external functions, it's better to write those as pure functions and keep the attribute access (and even more attributes updates) within the class code itself - this makes the code much easier to test, read and maintain. In you case this would looks like:

```
from calculate_function import function


class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = -2
        self.x = 1
        self.z, self.result = function(self.x)
```

calculate_function.py:

```
def function(x):
    z = 2
    result = z + x
    return z, result
```

The points here are that 1/ you can immediatly spot the creation of attributes `z` and `result` and 2/ you can test `function()` without a `Data` instance.

> I need to split class methods in several files.

This often means your class has too many responsabilities. Some parts of it can be delegated to pure functions like shown above. Some other parts, that need access to a common subset of your class attributes, can be delegated to other, smaller, specialized classes - but preferably using composition / delegation instead of inheritance (depending on concrete use cases of course).

Comment: yep that was my first approach to this problem but @deceze is said that is not proper one. As you have said i find this quite clear. Instead of passing `self.x` i used to pass `self`' to get all init variables

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi what deceze says is that having your function doing BOTH things (mutating the object and returning values) is inconsistant - and it is indeed. In my exemple above, the function doesn't mutate anything - it actually doesn't know anything about your `Data` class -, it just do some computations based on it's arguments and returns values.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need pass self inside the function
Why not do it like this:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = -2
        self.x = 1
        self.function()

    def function(self):
        self.z = 2
        self.result = self.z + self.x
```

Do wish to use another Class function or just a stand alone function?

Comment: that will not work if you split methods inside separated files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, using class inheritance:

```
-- function1.py --
class FunctionClass1():
     def function1(self):
             self.result = self.x + self.y

-- function2.py -- 
class FunctionClass2():
     def function2(self):
             self.result = self.result + self.z

-- data.py -- 
from function1 import FunctionClass1
from function2 import FunctionClass2 


class Data(FunctionClass1, FunctionClass2):
     def __init__(self):
             self.x = 1
             self.y = 2
             self.z = 3
             self.function1()
             self.function2()
```

Comment: that is looking nice. But there is a: `Unresolved attribute reference x, y ` inside function1

Comment: That is looking like inheritance abuse as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Shouldn't be, if you assigned them before calling method.But for safety you can add some checks and defaults for this variables in these methods

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Why? OP wants to split logic into multiple modules, that's exactly what inheritance is for.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin Nope. Inheritance implies a IS A relationship, and is mostly a static and restricted form of composition / delegation. Mixin classes can make sense when you have a same subset of operations to share between multiple classes, but they should only provide additional behaviour (not adding public attributes the main class depends on) - and even then they quickly become a PITA wrt/ readabilty and maintainance (been here, done that...). Better to do a _proper_ refactoring and use composition / delegation.

Comment: FWIW inheritance is one of the most overrated  OO features. The really important  points in OO are encapsulation (which your example kind of breaks) and polymorphic dispatch (which requires proper subtyping, cf Liskov Substitution Principle).

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin you may want to [read the GOF](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/design-patterns-elements/0201633612/) - not that much for the design patterns themselves (well, they are of interest too of course), but for the (long) introduction, which is probably one of the most enlightning text on OO design.